# how to number questions using class in CSS

Tags: html, css, css-counter

I have created a list of questions and plan to add more in the future. I want to number the questions using CSS 
for example each question is in a section as given below.

```
<section class = "question">The Question</section>
```

Is there any way to number them automatically using the "question" class ??

Comment: You probably should look at HTML Ordered List (ol) element. Rgds,

Comment: any idea how to achive this by jquery ??

Comment: I assume you are looking for CSS counters and have hence tagged it to the question. Please feel free to rollback if it is not the case.

Comment: So which one are you looking for? CSS or jQuery? Please make up your mind.

Comment: I got the idea from @j08691 using css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can with the :before pseudo-element and CSS counters:

```css
body {
  counter-reset: section;                   /* Set the section counter to 0 */
}
section.question::before {
  counter-increment: section;               /* Increment the section counter*/
  content:  counter(section) ": "; /* Display the counter */
}
```

```html
<section class="question">The Question</section>
<section class="question">The Question</section>
<section class="question">The Question</section>
<section class="question">The Question</section>
```

You can read more about CSS counters at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters and http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#generate.html#counters

Comment: This code will target and number all sections. I also have sections which have different classes. I only want to number sections with questions class. Do i need to modify the code ??